# What is the lexical scope of the success callback of the 'then' function of an angular promise?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, q, lexical-scope

I'm trying to understand why some of the dependecies injected (or other variables declared) in my controller are not available inside the success/error callback of the 'then' function of a deferred promise.

I've searched in angular $q's documentation and in several posts here but I'm not being able to answer my question... Maybe I'm not searching the right keywords, I don't know.

Here's a snippet of my controller with the questions that I want to know.
Thanks in advance!

```
(function () {
'use strict';
angular
    .module('app.aModule')
    .controller('mycontroller', MyController);

MyController.$inject = ['$controller', '$scope', 'myService'];

function MyController($controller, $scope, myService) {

    $scope.myProp;
    var myVariable1 = 'hello';

    //.............some code.................

    $scope.save = function(event) {
            var myVariable2 = 'World!';
            myService.post($scope.myProp).then(
                function (result) {
                    // 1. can I access to myVariable1 here?
                    // 2. can I access to myVariable2 here?
                    // 3. can I access to $scope or $controller dependency here?
                    // 4. can I access to myService dependency here?
                },
                function (error) {
                    // do something
                }
            );
        };

    //.............some code.................
}

})();
```

And here is the post method of my angular service:

```
 function post(data) {
        var deferred;
        deferred = $q.defer();

        $http.post(apiUrl + endpoint + 'post', data).then(function (result) {
            deferred.resolve(result);
        }, function (error) {
            deferred.reject(error);
        });

        return deferred.promise;
    };
```

Comment: Just debug. It is easy

Comment: @Mediator Hehe I've already did it but I would like to understand the theory behind. BTW, when debugging I only could access to $scope and myService dependencies (not to $controller and the other variables).

Comment: 1-3 answer is yes, not sure what you are refering to in 4th point, `$http.post` already returns promise, stop wrapping it with `deferred.promise` ...

Comment: Hi @mido! In fact, as I mentioned in my previous comment, I can only access to $scope and myService (an angular service that I've created and injected in the controller as you may see). I cannot access to the variables 1 and 2, and neither to the $controller

Answer (score 0):

It is not depends with promises.
You can't understand closure function.

A closure is a function having access to the parent scope(it is not angular scope), even after the parent function has closed.
If you write **myVariable1** or(and) **myVariable2** into function it makes it possible to see this varibales, but if you just debug it you can't see it(if you didn't write it).

Answers:
1 and 2 - depends how you do it.
3. $scope - yes. controller - can't understand what is mean.
4. same answer as 1 and 2.

Comment: I know what a closure is. I DID write the code so I DID debug it, and the result of the debugging is the one a answered to your previous non-useful comment.
Can you explain more about your answers regarding "depends how you do it"? It's a bit generic. $controller service is responsible for instantiating controllers.... but you should read more about angular if you can't understand this kind of things.

Comment: What you explained about turning the variables into functions doesn't make sense. If you understand what "parent scope" means you'd know that it's not a matter of being functions or variables.

Comment: I suggest create jsfiddle. Because you have to see myVariable1 and myVariable2. When I told about "depends how you do it" I mean you HAVE  TO write myVariable1 inside promise. IF you don't write you will not see it in debug.